# MySQL query slow on records increase

Tags: mysql

I have the below query that it is very slow to get a result 0.49 on a table with 550k records. More records there is on the table and more is getting slow (on 30k records was 0.027).
Maybe there is another way to achieve the result, i need to extract records with distance of 3 minute from eachother.
Which kind of optimization I can perform or query change?

```
  SELECT a.*, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%i") as dataora
  FROM schedules_trackings a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MIN(id) id
            , FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(x.created_at,y.created_at))/60)*60 delta
         FROM schedules_trackings x
         JOIN
             ( SELECT MIN(created_at) created_at
                 FROM schedules_trackings  where schedule_id = "3" and device_id = "10017"
             ) y
         GROUP
             BY delta
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id where schedule_id = "3" and device_id = "10017"
```

here table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `schedules_trackings` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `schedule_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `altitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `accuracy` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `heading` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `speed` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `activity` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `battery` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `segmentid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `odometer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `schedules_trackings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `device_id` (`device_id`,`schedule_id`,`created_at`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `schedule_id` (`id`,`created_at`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `schedules_trackings`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Please provide query execution plan - use EXPLAIN SELECT QUERY;

Answer (score 0):

Indexes:

```
schedules_trackings:  INDEX(schedule_id, device_id, created_at)
schedules_trackings:  INDEX(created_at, id)
```

*The order of the columns is important.*  Your existing indexes *may* be useful for some other queries, but not very useful for the current query.  Well, I doubt if the current (`id`,`created_at`) is useful, since it *begins* with the PK, thereby making it unlikely to ever be used.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

The table is about twice as big as needed; some speed is gained by shrinking the table.

- `DOUBLE` takes 8 bytes; `FLOAT` takes 4 and has about 7 digits of significance.
- `VARCHAR` for lat/lng makes them useless for arithmetic.
- etc.

Comment: with this index is getting worst 0.77. added table structure on top.

Comment: @user3348353 - I added to my Answer.